# Retrieving subscribers on a list

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I followed the instructions on this page https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_subscribers_on_a_list/

however the answer I get contains all the subscribers on all the lists, it does not seem to be filtering at all. 
Here is the soap body I am using, can someone look and see if I am missing anything:

```
  <soapenv:Body>
<ns2:RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns:ns2="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <ns2:RetrieveRequest>   
    <ns2:ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ns2:ObjectType>
    <ns2:Properties>ID</ns2:Properties>
    <ns2:Properties>Client.ID</ns2:Properties>
    <ns2:Properties>CreatedDate</ns2:Properties>
    <ns2:Properties>ListID</ns2:Properties>
    <ns2:Properties>ModifiedDate</ns2:Properties>
    <ns2:Properties>ObjectID</ns2:Properties>
    <ns2:Properties>Status</ns2:Properties>
    <ns2:Properties>SubscriberKey</ns2:Properties>
    <Filter type="par:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Property>ListID</Property>
         <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
         <Value>18618078</Value>  
     </Filter>
    <ns2:ContinueRequest></ns2:ContinueRequest>
    <ns2:QueryAllAccounts>true</ns2:QueryAllAccounts>
  </ns2:RetrieveRequest>
</ns2:RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the XML namespaces used in your call.  Notice the Filter tag doesn't have "ns2:" in it like the rest of the tags in that node. Due to this issue, the Filter tag is being ignored.